# no ocijdbc10 found in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, oracle-call-interface, oracleclient

I've got error-"no ocijdbc10 found in java.library.path" while starting tomcat server. But i have ocijdbc11 in my oracle11 installation. I've tried setting path variables for ojdbc14.jar and ojdbc6.jar.I've added even ocijdbc11 in my variable path.Please anyone tell a solution.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add ojdbc14.jar and ojdbc6.jar from oracle folder to your $TOMCAT_HOME/lib and restart it. You can also add these jars to your webapps/project-directory/WEB-INF/lib folder. By the way Mr. Nadeem only ojdbc6.jar is enough to work

Comment: you can add both libs either in tomcat/lib folder or project lib folder and this will start working

Comment: Can you explain why would he need both of them?

Comment: This is mechanism that Tomcat follows. Its reading libraries from lib folder

Comment: Those files are the same, built for different JDK/JDBC versions. DO NOT use them together. You can pick the one you need from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03

Comment: @Gergely Bacso he has oracle and oracle can have its jars file. OP may download wrong version that may create problem for him that's why I said him to just copy paste ojdbc file from there. By the way Mr. Nadeem only ojdbc6.jar is enough to work

Comment: Thanks guys...It worked when i removed ojdbc14.jar from javaclasspath and kept ojdbc6.jar

Comment: please vote up or mark answer if this helped you in any case. This pleased me to go a head and work more actively in this community

Comment: @nadeem You realized that this answer helped you but neither marked answer nor voted up.